# Pocket Chumash recommendations

Tags: product-recommendation, pentateuch-chumash

I'm looking for a new pocket Chumash to keep in my tallis bag for following along during leining. While there are a few features I'd like, but I'm fairly loose on some of them, if not all are available in one edition.

- Hebrew-only or with English commentary
- Text vocalised like the Keter Yerushalayim or R' Wolf Heidenheim, especially with regards to chataf vowels
- hardcover
- multiple haftarah traditions (eg. Ashkenaz, 'Edot haMizrach, Frankfurt a/M)
- margins sufficiently large to annotate alternate breakups of 'aliyot.
- clean type, not an *n*th generation offset
- *Not* a shnayim mikra edition

Comment: Hi Noach - You're requesting quite a bit! I'm unfamiliar with bullet items #2, #5 (do you mean you just want wide margins so that you can add your own notes?) an #6 (what is "nth generation offset"?)

Comment: @DanF [offset printing][1] is what gives many mid-20th century seforim their classic, difficult-to-read look. The more generations, the more difficult to read. For #5, I want notes of where the 'aliyot in the Frankfurt custom differ from the mainstream, which I will likely need to add myself.



  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_printing